# Threejs 2d to 3d with adjusted camera y position

Tags: three.js

I'm building a space game and figured out how to project a 2d click to 3d to get the direction for     bullets. If I shoot from first person view, everything goes well. However If i shoot from a third person view, having the camera set at a higher y position, the bullets will always go down to far.

Code being used:

```
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(
    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5
);
projector.unprojectVector( mouse3D, camera ); 
mouse3D.sub( camera.position );                
mouse3D.normalize();
```

with the camera being at `0, 10, 20`

How can i compensate the camera being at a higher y?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the most logic solution, but a simple solution would be to discard (set to 0) the `y` value of the directional vector. This way the vector will be in the XZ plane. And because you normalize it, no need to worry about the old value of `y`.

```
mouse3D.sub( camera.position );                
mouse3D.y = 0;
mouse3D.normalize();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I've tried what you suggested but I'm afraid it didn't work. I'm gonne review my bullet position update code as well, altough I don't expect the problem to lay there as all it does is use the translateX/y/z functions to update the bullets with their given direction.